# Query list in flutter based on user email

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am trying a filter a list of documents from a collection , one of a field in collection is Taskassignedto this field if equal to current user email .

i am trying to get data by using following code

```
  return await Firestore.instance.collection('Task').getDocuments();
```

i need to filter the collection where Taskassigned to is equal to current user email.
Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 final FirebaseUser user = await auth.currentUser();
    final useremail = user.email;
    return await Firestore.instance
        .collection('Task')
        .where(
          'Taskgivento',
        ).where("Taskgivento",isEqualTo: useremail)
        .getDocuments();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
return await Firestore.instance.collection('Task').where("Taskassigned", isEqualTo: firebaseUser.email).getDocuments();
```

`where()` query will check `Taskassigned` to is equal to current user email

Comment: I want it to filter based on current user email

Comment: still getting an error the getter email isnt defined for the class FirebaseUser

Comment: What is the email that you are using? The email in my answer is variable that you should have in your code

Comment: In your code, you have an email variable that the user writes correct? Then use that email in your code inisde the where()

Comment: the variable i used for email is email